# Proving that for $f\in C^2(a,\infty)$ then $\max_{(a,\infty)} |f'(x) |\le 4\max_{(a,\infty)}|f(x)|\max_{(a,\infty)} |f''(x) |$.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f\in C^2(a,\infty)$
and $M_k=\max_{(a,\infty)} |f^{(k)}(x) |$, $k=0,1,2$, prove that
$$M_1^2\le 4M_0M_2.$$

Firstly, I know that if $f, g\in C^2(a,\infty)$ so is $fg\in C^2(a,\infty)$.
Any hint on how to proceed is highly appreciated. So that I would know how to go about proving this if I am to use the given condition.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71126/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1549141/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2287603/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24M_1%5E2%5Cle%204M_0M_2%24)

Comment: Thank you @Martin. That saves me  a lot.