# Prob. 20, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: An equality which follows from Taylor's theorem and which remains valid for vector valued functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, inequality

Here is Prob. 20, Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Formulate and prove an inequality which follows from Taylor's theorem and which remains valid fro vector-valued functions.

And, here is the link to an earlier post of mine on Prob. 15, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition:

[Prob. 15, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: Prove that $M_1^2\leq M_0M_2$, where $M_0$, $M_1$, and $M_2$ are the lubs, resp., of ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281180/prob-15-chap-5-in-baby-rudin-prove-that-m-12-leq-m-0m-2-where-m-0-m)

As the inequality in Prob. 15 follows from Taylor's theorem and holds for vector-valued functions too, so it is a valid example in Prob. 20 too. Am I right?

Here is another example:

> Suppose $f$ is a real function defined on the interval $[a, b]$ such that $f^{(n-1)}$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, and $f^{(n)}$ exists in the segment $(a, b)$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Then there exists a point $x \in (a, b)$ such that 
>   $$ \left| f(b) - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(j)}(a)}{j!} (b-a)^j \right| \leq \frac{\left| f^{(n)}(x) \right| }{n!} (b-a)^n. \tag{1} $$ 
>   For a vector-valued function $\mathbf{f} = \left( f_1, \ldots, f_k \right)$ defined on $[a, b]$ such that $\mathbf{f}^{(n-1)}$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $\mathbf{f}^{(n)}$ exists in $(a, b)$, we note that if 
>   $$ \mathbf{f}(b) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{\mathbf{f}^{(j)}(a)}{j!} (b-a)^j, $$ then obviously, 
>   $$ \left| \mathbf{f}(b) - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{\mathbf{f}^{(j)}(a)}{j!} (b-a)^j \right|  \leq \frac{\left| \mathbf{f}^{(n)}(x) \right| }{n!} (b-a)^n. \tag{2} $$ 
>   Otherwise, we put $$ \mathbf{c} \colon= \frac{1}{ \left| \mathbf{f}(b) - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{\mathbf{f}^{(j)}(a)}{j!} (b-a)^j \right|  } \left( \mathbf{f}(b) - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{\mathbf{f}^{(j)}(a)}{j!} (b-a)^j \right) ,$$ 
>   and then define the function $g$ on $[a, b]$ by the formula $$ g(t) \colon= \mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{f}(t). $$ 
>   Then $g^{(n-1)}$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $g^{(n)}$ exists in $(a, b)$. So we can find a point $x \in (a, b)$ such that 
>   $$ \left| g(b) - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{g^{(j)}(a)}{j!} (b-a)^j \right| \leq \frac{\left| g^{(n)}(x) \right| }{n!} (b-a)^n,$$ 
>   which simplifies to (2) because $$\left| \mathbf{c} \right| = 1.$$

Am I right?

I would appreciate if some less trivial example could be supplied by the Math SE community.

Comment: Note that in Rudin, Taylor's theorem is stated in terms of some $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $[a,b]$, such that $f(\beta)=P(\beta)+\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(\beta-\alpha)^n$. In particular, we note that we may have $\beta <\alpha$.

Comment: @SomeStrangeUser yes, you're right, and this fact reduces a bit the triviality of the resulting inequality.